# When did this T-SQL became incorrect? Or have it always?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why does the following (two last) statements return different results. I'm almost 100% sure that they 'used' to return the same result (does anyone recall how this used to be in SQL server 6/2000?).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[color](
    [colorid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [title] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT color SELECT 1,'Red' UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Green' UNION ALL SELECT 3,'Blue'

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[membercolor](
    [memberid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [colorid] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT membercolor SELECT 10,1 UNION ALL SELECT 10,2 UNION ALL SELECT 10,3 UNION ALL SELECT 11,1 UNION ALL SELECT 11,2 UNION ALL SELECT 12,1

SELECT * FROM color
SELECT * FROM membercolor

-- red, green & blue
SELECT * FROM color a LEFT JOIN membercolor b 
    ON a.colorid=b.colorid AND b.memberid=11

-- red, green - but why?    
SELECT * FROM color a LEFT JOIN membercolor b 
    ON a.colorid=b.colorid WHERE b.memberid IS NULL OR b.memberid=11
```

Comment: Are you sure this wasn't just possible with old-style join syntax?

Comment: Can't remember, but I was pretty sure that it should have worked. After all - all rows from colors should be returned in a LEFT JOIN scenario. Filtering of the right table allows NULLs or a value, so I'm still trying to grasp the answers below...

Comment: Thank you all! I finally get it :)

Comment: To understand this you first have to run the query without WHERE clause, and then apply the WHERE conditions. Without the WHERE clause, you'll see that none of the results have a null in the memberID column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the FROM clause as a separate part of the processing than the WHERE clause (which every product has to pretend it is, from a standards perspective).

During a LEFT JOIN, the system will take each row from the left table, and attempt to find matches in the right table. If there are matches, then it will produce one row in the output for each matching row in the right table. *If there are no matches*, then it will produce a single row, with all columns from the right table set to NULL.

In your first query, this is indeed what happens. But in your second query, during the FROM clause processing, it manages to produce a row which matches the JOIN condition:

```
3   Blue      10    3
```

So it never produces a row with NULL values for those columns from the right table.

Now, when the WHERE clause is processed, your conditions exclude this row from the final result set.

As others have said, you may be remembering the pre-ANSI join syntax, which could produce surprising results.

Answer (score 3):

The `is null` check only works for `colors` that have no matching `membercolor` at all.

If any `membercolor` matches, you end up with a result set like:

```
color blue memberid 8
color blue memberid 9
color blue memberid 10
```

Applying the `where` clause filters out all blue rows:

```
memberid IS NULL OR b.memberid=11
```

If no `membercolor` matches, the result set looks like:

```
color blue memberid NULL
```

The `where` clause will allow this to pass.

Comment: Ah, I finally get it! In the second case the LEFT JOIN finds _another members row_ and this fullfills the join condition. Then the WHERE clause filters that out! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It was always this way (since 2000 at least) - to see why, check this other statement:

```
SELECT * FROM color a LEFT JOIN membercolor b 
    ON a.colorid=b.colorid
```

On the other hand, what you might have intended is:

```
SELECT * FROM color a LEFT JOIN membercolor b 
    ON a.colorid=b.colorid AND b.memberid=11 WHERE b.memberid IS NULL OR b.memberid=11
```